# Function call takes longer in composite class

Tags: c++, performance

Trying to understand run time performance with class composition, I wrote the following test code. In it, I compare the time taken to call a function directly as a member function of a class, versus to call it through a composite class that has the original class as a member.

It seems like the methods should take comparable time, but they don't: calling through the composite class takes almost twice as long.

Here's the code:

```
const int REPS(1e8);
const double INPUT(5.29);

class Base {
public:
  inline double BaseFunc(double x) const;
};

double Base::BaseFunc(double x) const {
  return 2.718*x + 3.14;
};

class Super {
public:
  inline double BaseFunc(double x) const;
private:
  Base b_; 
};

double Super::BaseFunc(double x) const {
  return b_.BaseFunc(x);
};

int main() {
  auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  // Construct objects.
  Base b;
  Super s;

  // Call to base directly.
  for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i)
    b.BaseFunc(INPUT);
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  // Call to base through composited class.
  for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i)
    s.BaseFunc(INPUT);
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  // Find average durations.
  auto diff1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1-t0).count();
  diff1 /= REPS;
  auto diff2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2-t1).count();
  diff2 /= REPS;

  std::cout << "Calling directly to base took " << diff1 << "nsec.\n";
  std::cout << "Calling to base through a composited class took " << diff2 << "nsec.\n";
}
```

Compiling with g++ Version 4.7.2, with -std=c++11 -O0 -Winline, I get:

```
Calling directly to base took 13nsec.
Calling to base through a composited class took 24nsec.
```

Why is there such a disparity between these two ways of calling essentially the same function? I figure that since everything is inlined (gcc doesn't tell me otherwise) these should be the same thing.

Am I thinking about this totally incorrectly? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

**Update** Thanks for all the help! I went back and put more in the function call (calling inner_product on a vector) and used all the result each repetition, to make sure gcc wasn't optimizing away anything. Then I turned on optimization. You all were right: the difference went away.

I think I learned two important things: 1) With optimization turned off, gcc won't even *try* to inline, so the -Winline flag is meaningless, and 2) There is no meaningful difference between these two ways of calling the function. I can confidently call member functions from within other classes!

Thanks again!

Comment: I think it kind of make sense.  A function is essentially a pointer to some memory, to call a function you need to de-reference that pointer.  Your composite call is a function call which calls another function inside of it so it would take a bit longer right?

Comment: You're thinking about it, that's the problem. It's unlikely to ever be a real bottleneck.

Comment: Your assumption that "everything is inlined" is certainly wrong since you explicitly _disabled_ all optimizations (including inlining) with `-O0`... (btw, according to `man g++`, `-finline-functions` is enabled at optimization level `-O3`.)

Comment: (Maybe your "(gcc doesn't tell me otherwise)" refers to the `-Winline`; however this warning is only triggered when the compiler tries to inline a function and fails (because its body is too complicated or whatever), but with `-O0` (and without `-finline-functions`) it _doesn't even try_ to inline. Well, that's how I get it. But I admit that's arguably confusing.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program was compiled unoptimized (`-O0`). This means that we cannot expect the usual code quality. In order to find out what the problem was we'd need to look at the generated code. Probably inlining did not occur (although requested by using `inline`). This might have doubled the number of runtime calls, therefore approximately doubling run time.

If the program was properly optimized, both loops would be removed entirely. I think this benchmark is moot and whatever the result is, it is meaningless. In production, full optimizations and a realistic workload would be performed.

Comment: "not fully unoptimized"... gotta love the double negative brain-teaser. Oh, but it was compiled fully unoptimized (`-O0`), not "not fully unoptimized" (i.e partially optimized). The `-Winline` enables a warning, not an optimization...

Comment: Dammit, I screwed that up ;-) Fixed.

Comment: "I think this benchmark is moot and whatever the result is, it is meaningless." Welcome to [tag:performance].

Answer (score 1):

`inline` is only a hint the compiler, not a requirement. In fact, most compilers ignore it alltogether.

You have supplied the compiler argument `-O0`, disabling all optimization. Since inlining is an optimization, it does not happen. This means that the call overhead occurs twice - explaining almost double the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To see if the function calls are inlined, you could look at the resulting assembly code.  On Linux, you could use `objdump -d` to do this.  If you don't want to wade through all of the assembly, and if you know what you're looking for, you could grep for the meaningful stuff:

```
objdump -d a.out | egrep "(main|BaseFunc|call)" | egrep "(main|BaseFunc)" | egrep -v "(jmp|jne)"
```

(Yes, that chain of egrep regexes could almost certainly be shortened if rewritten, but that's not the point.)

The result, if the functions are NOT inlined, will look similar to this:

```
08048700 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
 804879c:       e8 5f ff ff ff          call   8048700 <__libc_start_main@plt>
080488c0 <main>:
 804896e:       e8 65 02 00 00          call   8048bd8 <_ZNK4Base8BaseFuncEd>
 80489b5:       e8 50 02 00 00          call   8048c0a <_ZNK5Super8BaseFuncEd>
08048bd8 <_ZNK4Base8BaseFuncEd>:
08048c0a <_ZNK5Super8BaseFuncEd>:
 8048c30:       e8 a3 ff ff ff          call   8048bd8 <_ZNK4Base8BaseFuncEd>
```

Note within `main` the two calls to functions named `BaseFunc()` (`Base::BaseFunc()` and `Super::BaseFunc()`).

I changed your `-O0` to `-O1` and then I see something like this...

```
08048660 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
 80486dc:       e8 7f ff ff ff          call   8048660 <__libc_start_main@plt>
08048800 <main>:
```

...now you can tell that both function calls were inlined, and (in this case, likely) even the REPS loop itself may have been optimized away, since on my system both results were 0ns.

To prevent optimization of the loop, I added this global variable:

```
volatile long gCtr = 0;
```

...and in the function `Base::BaseFunc()`, I added this prior to the `return`:

```
  gCtr += 1;
```

...and now the result for both is 2ns, which seems believable.  Both `BaseFunc()` functions are inlined, but the loop is not optimized away.